# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on in window form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, syncfusion

I have 2 form in my window form application

**frmDashboad** and  **frmCompany**.

There is a button on frmDashboad form, and on click of that button I'm showing frmCompany as a Dialog.

This is my code.

```
private void btnCompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       new frmCompany().ShowDialog();
     }
```

My frmCompany form.

```
public partial class frmCompany : SfForm
    {
        public frmCompany()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Now When I close the frmCompany and again click on button to show frmCompany dialog again, if I repeat this process 5-6 times continiously then an exception is thrown.

```
'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'
```

This is complete stack trace.

```
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_InternalHandle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DestroyHandle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.SfToolTip.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
at Syncfusion.WinForms.Controls.SfForm.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at InventorySystem.UI.frmCompany.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in D:\Test\Code Sample\inventory-system\InventorySystem\InventorySystem.UI\frmCompany.Designer.cs:line 20
at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize()
```

If I replace `SfForm` with `Form` then there is no exception occured.

Comment: There are many question with similar title, but none of them solve my problem. so please don't mark duplicate. Thanks

Comment: Looks like a pretty ugly bug in the Syncfusion code.  That SfToolTip should have had its Dispose() method called when you closed the form, but that didn't happen.  Hopefully you can get to it to call Dispose() yourself, might not be easy.  Watch out for a tooltip appearing while using the form, that's where the trouble started.  Using Syncfusion support is best.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set following property false for `Form` or `sfDatagrid`.

- ShowValidationErrorToolTip